# getting error while executing my select query - Arguments are of wrong type , are out of acceptable range

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am getting an error while executing a SQL select query in VBA.
Error : Arguments are of wrong type , are out of acceptable range ,or are in conflict in one another.Please find my code below

```
Public Function Get Invoices()

Dim objConn As Object

Dim objRecordSet As Object

Dim objRecCmd As Object

strQuery = "Select Distinct [RECHNR] from [Sheet1$]"

strFolderPath = "\test1"

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set objRecCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objConn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFolderPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1""")

Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objRecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient

objRecCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn

objRecCmd.CommandText = strQuery

objRecordSet.Open objRecCmd, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

End Function
```

Error is coming in the line - objRecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient

Comment: your enum is not in Excel, for adUseClient, you'll need to get it's numeric value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursorlocationenum?view=sql-server-ver15   You can use a reference to ADO also, to make things easier

Comment: I am using excel as database.  your enum is not in excel - What do you mean by this point?

Comment: Exactly what it says, these are enums for the ADO library, not witihin Excel.  If you add a reference to microsof activex data objects you will bring them over, if not, you need to create your own in Excel VBA or use the numeric value in the link i attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code references the following:

```
adUseClient
adOpenKeyset
adLockOptimistic
```

These enums (short for enumerations - you might think of them as constants, or codewords for specific numbers - Google "What is an Enum" for further info) are not recognised by Excel, so it will assume that they are variables.

If you use `Option Explicit` in your code, Excel would tell you this.

Because these variables don't exist, Excel interprets them as 0. You will see below, 0 is not the value you want used in any of the cases. You need to use the correct number/code to get your script to request the right thing.

You have three options to do this:

**Option 1**

You could create variables named the same as the enums. You could put the following at the start of your code:

```
adUseClient = 3
adOpenKeyset = 1
adLockOptimistic = 3
```

This does work, but isn't recommended - as unlikely as it is, Microsoft could in theory change their coding and your script would start requesting very strange things until you realise and action a fix.

**Option 2**

You could replace your use of the enums with actual values. Swapping the enum name with the value above would solve the problem. But again, if Microsoft were to change things up in a later version of ADO, chaos might ensue.

**Option 3**

Reference the necessary library in your Project's References. Go to Tools > References and tick/select:

*Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset x.x Library*

In doing this, Excel becomes 'aware' of the real values - from the Library - and so should always use the correct one.